# Use async in Flask library

Tags: python-3.x, async-await

I try to btle.Peripheral() in Python3.6 and I want to use the connect function with a custom timeout. In the library, there is no timeout function so I want to use async to do this.

```
         def myfunction()
            ....

            async def coroutine(future):
                try:
                    await asyncio.wait_for( peripheral.connect(ble_mac_address), timeout=1)
                    future.set_result( OK)
                except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                    future.set_result( NOK)

            loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
            future = loop.create_future()
            asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
            ret = asyncio.run(coroutine(future))
            loop.close()
```

My function should have a timeout of 1 seconde if nothing happen. In my case, the function wait until the timeout of the ble function (20 secondes).

How could I do what I want properly?

Edit: it seems that the Flask multithread is not activate.
I try to modify the call of my flask app.run with threaded=True, but I still have the same behaviors

Here is a simple example to reproduce:

The server:

```
import asyncio
import json
import time

from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

from flask_cors import CORS

from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
from geventwebsocket.handler import WebSocketHandler

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'

@app.route('/new_recipe', methods=["POST"])
def new_recipe():
    print('MdtServer             :')
    print('MdtServer             : new_recipe')

    async def do_io(loop):
        print('io start')
        # await asyncio.gather(loop.run_in_executor(None, self.peripheral.connect(ble_mac_address)))
        await asyncio.gather(loop.run_in_executor(None, time.sleep(10)))
        print('io end')

    async def do_other_things(future: asyncio.Future, loop):
        print('doing other things')
        try:
            res = await asyncio.wait_for(do_io(loop), timeout=1)
            future.set_result('OK')

        except Exception as err:
            print('err '.format(err))
            future.set_result('NOK')

    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    future = loop.create_future()
    ret = loop.run_until_complete(do_other_things(future, loop))
    print('ret {}'.format(ret))
    print('ret future {}'.format(future))
    loop.close()
    # Generate JSON return
    answer = dict()

    return json.dumps(answer)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ## With Only flask
    app.run(threaded=True)
    ### WIth WSGIServer
    # http_server = WSGIServer(('localhost', 5000), app, handler_class=WebSocketHandler)
    # http_server.serve_forever()
```

The client:

```
import json
import requests

step_0 = dict()

request = f'Post on /new_recipe with data {json.dumps(step_0)}'
print(f" request > {request}")
get_request = requests.post('http://localhost:5000' + '/new_recipe',
                            data=json.dumps(step_0), headers={'content-type': 'application/json'})
response = get_request.json()
print(f" response > {response}")
```

Comment: you should probably take a look at https://sanic.dev/

Comment: @Loic I would prefer to be able to do this with Flask.

Comment: then you can install ```pip install flask[async]``` and do it this way : https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/async-await/